# Let $S=\{s_1, ..., s_k\}$ be the prime factors of $n$. Construct the set $E=\{e_1, ..., e_k\}$ of exponents so that $\prod_{i=1}^{k}s_i^{e_i}=n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given an integer $n$ and a set $S=\{s_1, s_2, ..., s_k\}$ of all prime factors of $n$, how can I construct the set $E=\{e_1, e_2, ..., e_k\}$ of exponents such that $\prod_{i=1}^{k}s_i^{e_i}=n$

Comment: what have you tried ? Also another thing does the "set" include duplicates ? if so it's a multiset.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I've tried $\log_{s_i}(n)-1$ for $e_i$. There are no duplicates in the set.

Comment: What do you mean "find?"  Is this something on a computer?

Comment: why $log_{s_i}(n)-1$ ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee intuition lol. I'm no mathematician.

Comment: @WillJagy I mean calculate. Yes it's on a computer.

Comment: I'm not either ( I do bug quite a few mathematical people online though), maybe try without the minus 1 ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee doesn't work. The issue with log-1 is that the exponents are too large.

Comment: try it with {2,3} for 6 doh realized this isn't a log thing at all, it's a valuation one.

Comment: If you have a list of prime factors and a large number, call it $n,$ you start with $p_1$ and, as long as $n$ is divisible by $p_1,$ replace $n$ by $n / p_1$ and increase the counter for the exponent of $p_1.$ Then do the same for $p_2,$ and so on. If your list of primes is complete, this is guaranteed to terminate with $n$ reduced to $1.$

Comment: Um...  If $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ is the unique prime factorization, isn't the set of exponents that you want simply the set $\{k_i\}$?  What exactly is your question?

Comment: @fleablood he's asking for the $k_i$

Comment: The question I would ask is how did you get the prime factors but not the exponents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pseudo code.

Let $n$ be the number.

Let $(p_1,...... p_m)$ be the list of  prime factors.

Let $i = 1$.

while $(i \le m)${

...$e_i = 0$

...while $(p_i| n)${

......$n = n/p_i;$

......$e_i ++;$

...}
...$i++;$

}

Comment: And you can replace $p_i$ by $i$ it works too

Comment: @NorbuTsering That's alright. Why you prefer decreasing order to increasing order? If you have, somehow, been supplied with all the primes that might be necessary, all that would appear to matter is consistent labeling, so that an index $i$ refers to a prime $p_i$ from the list and an exponent $e_i$ from the list, and $p_i^{e_i}$ is the correct factor..

Comment: You defined the $p_i$ as the n-tuple of primes $S$, so you already know which appear in the factorization of $n$; in this case the ordering of the prime numbers $p_i$ is negligible.

Comment: Unless you don't know which primes are in $S$.

Comment: The p_i were from a list the op claimed was known.  If we do not know the prime factors we can find them but we must start we 2.  (1 will give an infinite loop).  And it'd be *highly* inefficient not to put some prime testing in.  Oh, and I made a *very* serious indexing error, that I'm surprised none of you caught.  I have n as the number but also as the index of the number of prime factors.  That obviously won't work.

Comment: Editting typoes and formating are okay, but rewriting to change the intent is not.   {$p_1, ..... , p_m$} is the list of prime factors that was given (I suppose they can be called an "m-tuple" that isnt really relevant and imo not the correct concept.)   and no, they are *not* arranged in any particular order.